# What is in the box in Rear Window?

Tags: rear-window

Towards the end of Rear Window, we find out Thorwald dug up what was buried beneath the flowers, as the neighbors' dog got too inquisitive. He moved what he dug up to a hat box in his apartment.

What did he dig up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [**American Film Institute**](http://www.afi.com/members/catalog/DetailView.aspx?s=&Movie=51318) has a synopsis that explains:

> The police apprehend Thorwald, who confesses that **he deposited most of his wife’s body in the East River, except for her head, which he first buried in the garden and then packed in a hatbox.**